# Is there anything wrong with my use of AND in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my original C# code, which I get no results after running it (server runs MSSQL):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    SAMPLETYPEID = 'Environment'
    AND
    (
        BATCHDT BETWEEN '" + batchdt_from + "'AND '" + batchdt_to + "'
    );
```

and when I run it, it looks like this and give me no error while running:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    SAMPLETYPEID = 'Environment'
    AND
    (
        BATCHDT BETWEEN '2018.04.23' AND '2018.04.25'
    );
```

To solve the issue, I have tried to break down the SQL to two different queries, to see if those two work fine, at least separately:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE SAMPLETYPEID = 'Environment';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (BATCHDT BETWEEN '2018.04.23' AND '2018.04.25');
```

and it DOES work fine. I get results from both queries.

I am stuck at this point and would appreciate your comment on this.

Comment: Is it possible that there do not exist any records where both conditions are satisfied?

Comment: There just might be no rows satisfying both conditions? That's the nature of `AND`...

Comment: 1. **DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENATION IN SQL!** Use parameters! 2. What is the data-type of `BATCHDT`? (I'm surprised your query works at all because `yyyy.MM.dd` is not ISO-8601, I wonder if SQL Server is either being permissive in the first case and misinterpreting the strings in the second case - especially if your code runs with different locale/culture settings.

Comment: @dktaylor,  I suspected that as well, so I looked up the data collected from the 2nd separate query, which gets only data within a certain period and then I looked into see if there were records with SAMPLETYPEID = 'Environment'. and there were records...... I just don't know why this is happening...

Comment: Perhaps you want `OR`.  It would appear to do what you want to do with `AND`.

Comment: @Dai, thanks, will change the code with parameters. Since I am not running the query on a console, but on a VS 2015, I don't know the exact type of BATCHDT but assume this is a character(NVARCHAR). and about the date formats, I do prefer YYYY-MM-DD but someone has set that way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I want a AND operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving date in string format. `BETWEEN` clause will work on string variables. Try to convert `BATCHDT` in date and then use `BETWEEN` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE SAMPLETYPEID = 'Environment' AND ( CONVERT(DATE,BATCHDT) BETWEEN '2018.04.23' AND '2018.04.25' );
```

This may help you.

Answer (score -1):

`2018.04.23` is not normal syntax for date literals. Better to use ISO8601 syntax, which uses `-` for separators within the date portion. Going further, in Sql Server specifically for legacy reasons it's better to use the ISO8601 *unseparated* format for date-only literals:

```
20180423
```

Date+Time values should use the "regular" ISO8601 format:

```
2018-04-23T18:13:21
```

or

```
2018-04-23T18:13:21.2345
```

Better still, the question looks lot like it's showing client code using string concatenation. That's **NOT GOOD**. In addition to these format issues, the technique is also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Better to use parameterized queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE SAMPLETYPEID = 'Environment' AND (BATCHDT BETWEEN @BatchDt_From AND @BatchDT_To);
```

Now your C# code can set the parameter values using .Net DateTime objects, and ADO.Net will handle the formatting for you.

Comment: My record has all BATCHDT in YYYY.MM.DD formats. Will this query, with YYYY-MM-DD format, work on my data as well?

Comment: That's even **worse**. It's means you have a varchar rather than datetime column.

Comment: You're right. Thus batchdt_from is a string object, converted from a DateTime object by using ToString method.

Comment: Your best solution will be **ALTER** the table, to convert this column to a `DateTime` type, and also convert the C# code to use a parameterized query for these values. If you **EVER** find yourself converting a C# DateTime value to a string for use in SQL, you're doing something **VERY** wrong.

Comment: Agree with your best solution but not so sure if this will be a feasible answer cuz the system is fully validated and the size of the system is pretty big...